# How can I empty my dropdown selection with my keyboard in an HTML5 select element?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

At the moment when you open a dropdown by pressing "enter" after focussing on the element you can type in letters with your keyboard to go to the desired selection. For example in this dropdown:

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>America</option>
  <option>Belgium</option>
  <option>Brazil</option>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>Denmark</option>
  <option>Egypt</option>
<select>
```

When I open the dropdown with the "enter" key I can type in letters like "BE" to go to Belgium or "E" to go to Egypt. Is there a way to go back to the **empty** option with your keyboard? I have tried almost every possible key combination.

I would love to achieve this without using javascript.

Fiddle link to try out: https://jsfiddle.net/04kaje9e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By testing every single key on my keyboard I figured out these key combos for the select dropdown:

I also found other keys that can be usefull:

```
"Page up" : go to top of viewable list
"Page down" : go to bottom of viewable list
"Home": go to top of total list
"End" : go to bottom of total list
```

Answer (score -1):

Just empty the dropdown value on focusout. Once you select any value from dropdown then after pressing "Tab" key following jquery function will execute.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
  <option></option>
  <option>America</option>
  <option>Belgium</option>
  <option>Brazil</option>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>Denmark</option>
  <option>Egypt</option>
<select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#dropDown").on("focusout", function(){
            $('#dropDown').val('');
         });
     });
</script>
```